# jQuery form submission AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I am obviously missing something with jQuery, form submission and AJAX. The PHP back-end and the JSON encoding work fine. But when the form is submitted it is like
the data is submitted twice and the values going into the form are `null`.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validated = $("#loginForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessage",
        wrapper: "li",
        rules: {
            username: "required",
            password: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter your username.",
            password: "Please enter your password."
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.err == true) {
                        $("#errorMessage").text(res.msg);
                    } else {
                        window.location = res.url;
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#errorMessage").text("There was an error processing form.");
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you using firebug ? .. 'it is like the data is...' suggests you aren't monitoring your XHR calls effectively .

Comment: mind making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page? Is the validate plugin working? Also, you have a syntax error (extra comma) after the `error` option.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle of this and it seems that the code should work. In the firebug i saw that the request is send correct with all form date. I noticed that if the dataType property is defined the responded data type has to be correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vtAw/